# The best way to manage a dynamic goroutine pool

Tags: go, pool, goroutine

Let's say I have a task provider - readable channel, it may or may not provide a task(depends on work load)
Specific is so that there may be no work for hours and then there can be a sudden bump in tasks

I want to let my goroutine pool grow from 1 to N where N is the max concurrency when work appears and then automatically collapse down to 1 where there was no work for a goroutine for longer than X sec to avoid memory/cpu waste.

I could have used just a fixed pool, as goroutines are dirt cheap, but I don't like an idea of having thousands of idling goroutines I may have a better use for those resources(should be mostly ram but still)

Collapsing part is rather easy

```
for {
    timeoutTimer := time.NewTimer(WORKER_ROUTINE_TIMEOUT)

    select {
    case taskContext, isBatchRunning := <-runner.tasksCh:
        if !isBatchRunning {
            log.Print("task provider is closed, quit worker goroutine")
            return
        }

        runner.job.Process(&taskContext)
    case <-timeoutTimer.C:
        return
    }
}
```

But i'm not sure how to make pool grow dynamically, i.e. on which condition spawn a new one

A priority for this pool is being able to react fast on increased loading and expand up to N(max concurrency) goroutines, with ability to eventually collapse to a more reasonable numbers(1 at min) when work load decreased

P.S. I saw a https://github.com/Jeffail/tunny package, but it looks like it does not have anything similar to adaptive scaling of the current pool size. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: It's very uncommon to use a pool of goroutines, since managing them is usually more overhead than dispatching them when needed.

Comment: Also, if you're not aware, the stack for a single goroutine is only 2k, and that stack space isn't (currently) reclaimed but saved for future goroutines. If a pool does make the solution easier, adjusting it dynamically doesn't save you much, if anything.

Comment: Thing is, I have multiple task queues and a single go process takes tasks from those queues. If some queue is depleted but eventually had work to allow 1000 concurrency(1000 simultaneously running goroutines) I have 1000 idle goroutines right now, but I could use them in handling stuff from another queue... Though probably i'm digging to deep and over-optimizing

Comment: Just create new goroutines for each job. Creating a goroutine literally takes  nanoseconds. If you need to limit the concurrency, you can used a buffered channel.

Comment: I agree with JimB's suggestion of creating a goroutine for each job. You could also keep a count of how many are running with sync/atomic and do some profiling to find a max number of goroutines so your program doesn't blow up with a bump.

Comment: You might consider a sync.Pool  https://godoc.org/sync#Pool

Comment: Me too; still looking for the best way to do this. Meanwhile I've implemented a worker pool I use https://github.com/dc0d/workerpool.

Comment: Do *not* create a goroutine per job if you want it to scale well. Read about how someone did the same thing [here](https://www.facebook.com/ben1sandler) (using a pool of workers and a queue).

The article is titled "Handling 1 Million Requests per Minute with Go"

Comment: idk why Ben linked his facebook profile, but the actual link to the article is this:
http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/

which i would say is close to this open source goroutine worker pool implementation.
https://medium.com/@j.d.livni/write-a-go-worker-pool-in-15-minutes-c9b42f640923

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure that a pool is what you need. Goroutines are fast to launch, and you probably don't need to keep them ready all the time.

For this task I would use a simple semaphore. It's really easy to implement a semaphore in Go using channels. You can see my personal example [here](https://github.com/pavel-kazhavets/syncx/blob/master/semaphore.go).

You just create a semaphore with a desired capacity (which will be your maximum number of allowed goroutines) and then:

1. Acqiure the semaphore on goroutine start
2. Release it on goroutine end

Simple as that.
And don't worry about the need to launch them on demand; it is really over-optimizing.